# What's the maximum number of rows per single read/write transactions in Azure Storage Table

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-storage

We are investigating the performance of Azure storage table, what we want to know is **the maximum number of rows per single read and write transactions** for table, any official documentation can be referred?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write up to 100 rows in a single table storage transaction.  Assuming that all of the rows/entities have the same PartitionKey.

With respect to reading, you can read up to 1000 rows in one storage transaction.  Once again, assuming the same PartitionKey

Comment: What if not the same `PartitionKey`? I cannot use the batched operation?

Comment: That's correct.  Entities with different partition keys can potentially reside on different servers

Comment: One correction - `With respect to reading, you can read up to 1000 rows in one storage transaction. Once again, assuming the same PartitionKey`: Though it is true that a single read can read up to 1000 entities but there's no restriction of same PartitionKey. Your read operation may span across multiple partitions. Please see "Remarks" section on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179421.aspx. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri Okay. By the way, does the read operation also has the `total payload no more than 4MB in size limitation, just like the patched operation`?

Comment: 4MB restriction is for batch write operations only.

Comment: @GauravMantri All right, I think I have got all the answers. Thanks again.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have seen continuation tokens being issues for get requests far below 1000.  Doesn't that imply that PKey is the driving reason for them?

Comment: Not necessarily true ... from what I understand that you get continuation tokens if the query execution takes more than 5 seconds or when query results in crossing physical partitioning boundary (not logical). You may see getting data from across partitions in one result. I think it boils down to how storage engine is physically partitioning your data.

Comment: @GauravMantri actually, I wrote a sample, which insert 1200 entities firstly to the table, then retrieve it, I can indeed get all 1200 entities, no limitation exists, quite strange.

Comment: Are you using `QueryEntities` function by any chance? This method internally handles continuation token. Run Fiddler in the background and you will see multiple requests to table storage.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have post a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821093/does-the-azure-storage-table-query-entities-really-has-number-limitations).