# Return more than 1000 entities of a Windows Azure Table query

Tags: azure, odata, azure-table-storage

My question is exactly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615673/how-to-get-more-than-1000-entities-from-an-azure-table-storage-query). However, the Azure Storage API has changed and all answers I can find for this question deal with the old version. How do handle queries that return more than 1000 items in the current API version? The query fetching less than 1000 items looks like this:

```
var query = new TableQuery<TermScoreEntity>()
            .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal,    Name));

var table = _tableClient.GetTableReference("scores");

foreach (var termScoreEntity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))            
    result.Add(termScoreEntity.RowKey, termScoreEntity.Score);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to retrieve more than 1000 entities with your above code? I think use simple `ExecuteQuery` is enough.

The documentation only said it has **1,000** limitation for pure REST requests, the `ExecuteQuery` API internally use this rest api, but automatically cut to multiple requests, each of them has a limitation of **1,000**.

So if you use the .NET package, you don't need to worry about this limitation, the library already handle this for you. You can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821093/does-the-azure-storage-table-query-entities-really-has-number-limitations) for more information.

Here is some key code for `ExecuteQuery` from Azure SDK, you would find actually the max number is `9223372036854775807L` if you don't specify the `take` number:

```
internal IEnumerable<DynamicTableEntity> Execute(CloudTableClient client, CloudTable table, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext)
{
  CommonUtility.AssertNotNullOrEmpty("tableName", table.Name);
  TableRequestOptions modifiedOptions = TableRequestOptions.ApplyDefaults(requestOptions, client);
  operationContext = operationContext ?? new OperationContext();
  return CommonUtility.LazyEnumerable<DynamicTableEntity>((Func<IContinuationToken, ResultSegment<DynamicTableEntity>>) (continuationToken =>
  {
    TableQuerySegment<DynamicTableEntity> local_0 = this.ExecuteQuerySegmented((TableContinuationToken) continuationToken, client, table, modifiedOptions, operationContext);
    return new ResultSegment<DynamicTableEntity>(local_0.Results)
    {
      ContinuationToken = (IContinuationToken) local_0.ContinuationToken
    };
  }), this.takeCount.HasValue ? (long) this.takeCount.Value : long.MaxValue);
}
```

Comment: Absolutely correct, I don't know why I was thinking it doesn't work. Must have been something I've missed there. Thanks for the good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct, and basically looks the same as http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/#retrieve-all-entities - "How to: Retrieve all entities in a partition"

Are you sure there are more than 1000 entities in that partition?  You can check this a couple different ways:

1. Use Visual Studio or some other storage explorer to run the same query and see how many results you get.
2. Use Fiddler while running your code and see if there are continuation tokens being returned in the response.  If there are continuation tokens then the code you are using should automatically follow them and create a new request.  If there are no continuation tokens then that means there are no more entities matching your query.

Comment: The article you've linked is the Getting Started tutorial and they probably don't consider queries with more than 1000 rows at this point. However, I've worked it out and will post the answer...

Comment: I don't know, what I did there, you're absolutely right!! I deleted my answer.