# What is the limit on the query result size in Azure Table?

Tags: azure-table-storage

I'd like to know whether there is any limit on the size of a query result in the Azure Table storage? e.g. if I query for a partition and it contains many records, is there any issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1000 entities is the maximum returned in a single query transaction, after that point the service will return a continuation token.

Please see the docs on [query entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179421.aspx).

Comment: Not true that 1,000 is max rows unless it has changed since this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615673/how-to-get-more-than-1000-entities-from-an-azure-table-storage-query

Comment: I'm confused -- what about that post indicates 1000 isn't the max for table?

Comment: The REST API has a limit of 1000 rows per request. The .NET SDK uses the REST API underlying, but fetches the result in batches of 1000, so itself supports > 1000 records. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26990231/3570096

Comment: OK so I guess table storage isn't for me. Back to SQL Server!