# Multiple call to Azure Table storage to request less than 10 rows

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

We are querying Azure Table storage using `TableQuery` to retrieve data. Table contains almost 50,000 entities and my query returns less than 10 records.

Everything works fine. Problem comes when we load test it. To retrieve those less than 10 record, our app is sending 5 to 8 chain of requests with `ContinuationToken`.

**Question**: How to stop Azure Table Provider from sending multiple requests (5 to 7 sec per request) for retrieving less than 10 records? Note: This happens only when we load test our app.

There requests are clearly captured in App Insights.
[image]

Here is the Table Storage request urls (top 3) captured by App Insights. Note: Each request takes long time to complete.

```
https://redacted.table.core.windows.net:443/Redacted?$filter=%28PartitionKey%20eq%20%27RedactedA%27%29%20and%20%28RedactedB%20eq%20%2763601%27%29

https://redacted.table.core.windows.net:443/Redacted?$filter=%28PartitionKey%20eq%20%27RedactedA%27%29%20and%20%28RedactedB%20eq%20%2763601%27%29&NextPartitionKey=1%2112%21WmlwQ29kZXM-&NextRowKey=1%218%21MTU4Nzc-

https://redacted.table.core.windows.net:443/Redacted?$filter=%28PartitionKey%20eq%20%27RedactedA%27%29%20and%20%28RedactedB%20eq%20%2763601%27%29&NextPartitionKey=1%2112%21WmlwQ29kZXM-&NextRowKey=1%218%21MjIzMzY-
```

Here is our table query

```cs
TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity> dynamicQuery = cloudTable.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>();
var query = dynamicQuery.Where(x => x.PartitionKey == tableStorageMeta.PartitionKey &&
                               x.Properties[searchField].StringValue == searchValue).Select(x => x);
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @Klemikaze I have updated my post to include the question part directly

Comment: I believe that this might be helpfull...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231939/what-is-the-limit-on-the-query-result-size-in-azure-table

Comment: @Klemikaze But I am retrieving less than 10 records. Also, this doesn't happen when I test it locally. This happens only when we load test our application.

Comment: Ah I see now. That is strange. Ha. Could it be... Could it be that the LINQ expression is not executed at server side, but rather the entire table is loaded to client, that then executes the WHERE method? EDIT: That is stupid suggestion, forget it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: How to stop Azure Table Provider from sending multiple
> request for retrieving less than 10 records?

Simple answer is that you can't (other than optimizing your query). For executing a query, Azure Table Storage allocates a fixed amount of time to execute that query (5 seconds). If the query execution takes more time than that, Azure Table Storage returns whatever data it has fetched so far (subject to a maximum of 1000 entities) and if more data is available it would return a continuation token.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-timeout-and-pagination):

> A query against the Table service may return a maximum of 1,000 items
> at one time and may execute for a maximum of five seconds. If the
> result set contains more than 1,000 items, if the query did not
> complete within five seconds, or if the query crosses the partition
> boundary, the response includes headers which provide the developer
> with continuation tokens to use in order to resume the query at the
> next item in the result set.

Comment: Seems as the right answer, I will research more and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Table Storage is optimized for working with the `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` fields. It automatically indexes your entities using these in a single clustered index, hence the reason that point queries are the most efficient to use. There are no indexes other than that on the clustered index on the PartitionKey and RowKey.

Your query is a Partition Scan (3rd best option), since you're querying on other fields too. This might be the reason why there are multiple query executions going out: the entire partition needs to be scanned.

> Third best is a Partition Scan that uses the PartitionKey and filters on another non-key property and that may return more than one entity. The PartitionKey value identifies a specific partition, and the property values select for a subset of the entities in that partition. For example: `$filter=PartitionKey eq 'Sales' and LastName eq 'Smith'`

Source: [Design for querying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-for-query)

Comment: Hmm Interesting, I can combine you answer with @GauravMantri answer and say, Since I have less optimized query it takes more time to process it so it will exceed the 5 sec time limit and returns the current result with a continuation token.

Comment: Is there a way to index the custom fields?

Comment: Within a storage account, there is not. The article I linked to has some options on secondary indexes. A different option would be to migrate to Cosmos DB. It supports the Table API and indexes all fields.

Comment: Interesting option, I will consider that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want advanced indexing options without having to de-normalize your data to efficiently query smaller partitions, you can use Cosmos DB Table API as the backing store for the latest [Azure.Data.Tables](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.Tables/) client. Cosmos automatically indexes all fields rather than just the PK and RK for Storage Tables.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/introduction